# Protocol " "https" unsupported or disabed in libcurl

Tags: curl, https, libcurl

As you can see i have this peculiar error with the extra double quote specifying i have a https protocol error. The curl version i have installed supports https. Does the double quote have anything to do with the error?

Here is the error msg:
Protocol ""https" not supported or disabled in libcurl

Comment: Please give the context in which you're seeing this error, and your log outputs. This error can happen for multiple reasons, not just double quotes. The error message does not necessarily mean you can't accomplish your goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The protocol scheme **you used** is put within double quotes, indicating that you passed in a URL that starts with a double quote!

Don't do that, that's not a legal URL and obviously libcurl doesn't approve!